# SwiftUI: Center button text in List

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, watchos

Is it possible to center button text, if the button is located a in List?

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(["1", "2"], id: \.self) {
                Text("\($0)…").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            }

            Button("Action button") {}
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot of the result - button has incorrect (left) alignment]

PS:

I tried this: `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)`
But it doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found solution:

```
Button{} 
label: {
    Text("Action").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
}
```

Comment: This will affect the alignment of the dividing line, how to deal with it

Comment: This also doesn't make the list row highlight on tap. Only on a longpress...

Answer (score -2):

Use Text and a TapGesture embedded in a GeometryReader. Plus, to make it more tappable, use `.contentShape(Rectangle())`.

```
GeometryReader { metrics in
    List {
        ForEach(["1", "2"], id: \.self) { text in
            Text("\(text)…").frame(width: metrics.size.width, alignment: .center)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    print(text, "pressed")
                }
        }
    }
}
```